# Vue CLI 3 prevent cache busting for certain output files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm building a chrome extension with vue cli 3.  I've got the basics working well, but I was hoping to also run my content and background javascript through the build process instead of just putting them into my public folder and copying it into dist.  This is mostly just so I can use import/export to clean up my file structure.

I was able to add them as new "pages" in the vue config and even without the html template file, they get built properly and moved into dist.

The problem is, they then get the cache busting string appended to their filename so I'm unable to reference them in the extension manifest.  For example, `background.js` becomes `background.d8f9c902.js`

Is it possible to tell the vue config that certain "pages" should not get the cache busting?  The documentation [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) does not seem to expose that as a parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filename hashing can be disabled for all files:
https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing

It works in my case using below vue.config.js:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: true,
  filenameHashing: false
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works for me as well.  I suppose it cannot be done on a per-output basis but I don't think cache busting will be needed for any files in a chrome extension.